# How to get one row of info from .Csv file with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

**The powershell script:**

```
$test = import-csv “C:\CSVFiles\test.csv”
ForEach ($item in $test)
{
$Name = $item.(“Name”) 
$property = $item.("property")
$location = $item.(“location”)

Write-Output "$Name=$Name"
Write-Output "Property=$property"
Write-Output "Location=$location"
}
```

This script shows all the data for name,property and location for each row. I want the results to only show the data of one row;for example the row: n1;13;computer

The Cvs file =

```
Name;property;location
n1;13;computer
n2;65;computer
n3;12;tablet
n4;234;phone
n5;123;phone
n6;125;phone
```

What the current script spits out:

```
Name=n1
Property=13
Location=computer
Name=n2
Property=65
Location=computer
Name= n3
Property=12
Location=tablet
Name=n4
Property=234
Location=phone
Name=n5
Property=123
Location=phone
Name=n6
Property=125
Location=phone
```

Comment: Don't use a `ForEach` then. Use `$test[0]` or whatever index you need.

Comment: Do you want to list x-th entry or filter that based on property value? Also, you can skip assigning values to variables and use `Write-Output "Name=$($item.Name)"`

Comment: @Lieven sorry i did not notice your comment, i am new around here :). I am not familliar with where i would put this $test[0] to in the script? I tried to put it on the place of ForEach.

Comment: @Mark - LotPings' answer is pretty comprehensive. Better than what I can put in comments.

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to select a Row of a csv and to present the data

For demonstration I use an inline csv with a here string.

```
$Test = @"
Name;property;location
n1;13;computer
n2;65;computer
n3;12;tablet
n4;234;phone
n5;123;phone
n6;125;phone
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -delimiter ';'
```

---

```
> $test[0]

Name property location
---- -------- --------
n1   13       computer
```

---

```
> $test | where-object Name -eq 'n1'

Name property location
---- -------- --------
n1   13       computer
```

---

```
> $test | where-object Name -eq 'n1' | Select-Object Name,property

Name property
---- --------
n1   13
```

---

```
> $test | where-object Name -eq 'n1' | ForEach-Object {"Name:{0} has property: {1}" -f $_.Name,$_.property}
Name:n1 has property: 13
```

**Once imported the csv rows contents are converted to objects**

If you want to get the original row of the csv matching a criteria don't import but:

```
> Get-Content "C:\CSVFiles\test.csv" | Select-String '^n1'

n1;13;computer
```

`^n1` is a regular expression anchoring the pattern at line begin.

```
Select-String -Path "C:\CSVFiles\test.csv" -Pattern '^n1'
```

Is the same without a pipe

Answer (score 0):

So your current output is having 3 objects that are having 3 headers majorly. 
One is *Name*; Second one is *Property* and the third one is *Location*.

As part of solution, you can either pull the records by specifying the index value or you can use the .Headername to pull all the sets of same object. Like:

Avoiding Foreach and accessing with `$test[0]` or `$test[1]`

Or you can use like: `$test.Name` directly to have all of the names from the csv

Comment: Okey Ranadip thank you so much for answering! How would you use the "$test[0] or $test[1]" -option here, if the values of only "name" and "property" are needed from the first row (n1;13;computer) ?

Comment: Just use this:
$test[0] | Select Name, Property