# Powershell Create-item creates multiple folders on list

Tags: powershell

[Location.csv Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BkFQ.png) I'm trying to create a single folder by prompting the user for userID and the group used to map the home folder.

The below script creates the user's home folder in each location and not in the location matching the prompt.

Running the script without the foreach loop doesn't work.

```
$Locations = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\CreateHomeFolder\Location.csv"

$UserName = Read-Host "Enter User Logon Name"
$UserGroup = Read-Host "Enter User's Home drive group"

foreach($Location in $Locations.Location){
    if ($Locations.Groups -eq $UserGroup){
        New-Item -Name $UserID -Path $Locations.Location -ItemType Directory -Verbose
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Remove `.Location` in `foreach($Location in $Locations.Location)`. Inside the loop use `$Location` not `$locations`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went back to the drawing board, refined my google search and found the solution to be:

`$Locations = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\CreateHomeFolder\Locations.csv" | Where-Object Groups -eq $UserGroup | select Location`

`New-Item -Name $UserName -Path $Locations.Location -ItemType Directory -Verbose`

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you have the variables wrong. The iterating variable is `$location` and in each iteration it is an object taken from the array `$locations`.

Use

```
foreach($Location in $Locations){
    if ($Location.Groups -eq $UserGroup){
        New-Item -Name $UserID -Path $Location.Location -ItemType Directory -Verbose
    }
}
```

Comment: I hear you, however the file i'm importing is a .csv and not a text file. My understanding is that I need to reference the "location" coloumn.

I guess the question should be, how do i select the location that matches the group from input?

Comment: @Nuisance Did you try? That is exactly what the loop now does.. importing a csv creates an array of objects that you iterate through. Each of these objects have two properties: Groups and Location. You need to fix the undefined variable `$UserID` still though.. (should be `$UserName`)

Comment: went back to the drwaing board, refined my google search and found the solution to be:


`$Locations = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\CreateHomeFolder\Locations.csv" | Where-Object Groups -eq $UserGroup | select Location
New-Item -Name $UserName -Path $Locations.Location -ItemType Directory -Verbose`

Comment: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50852860/how-to-get-one-row-of-info-from-csv-file-with-powershell) @Theo, this is the article that pointed me to a shorted solution.

Comment: @Nuisance Sure, there are more ways of doing what you wanted, but your question was what was wrong in your foreach approach..

Answer (score 0):

[Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65452055/45375) addresses your immediate problem.

[Your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65455455/45375) improves on your original approach, though by not using
`select -ExpandProperty Location` - note the use of `-ExpandProperty`  (`select` is the built-in alias for the [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) cmdlet) - it creates unnecessary duplication (and processing overhead) by having to refer to `Location` *twice*.

Another option is to use direct property access:

```
New-Item -Name $UserName -ItemType Directory -Verbose -Path (
  (
    Import-Csv C:\Scripts\CreateHomeFolder\Locations.csv | 
       Where-Object Groups -eq $UserGroup
  ).Location
)
```